# Helpers are unavailable in rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Defined in `app/helpers` is a module called `SessionsHelper`. When attempting to access those methods  from `spec/requests/*` I receive a `NoMethodError`.

What causes this problem?  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design, if you want to use your helper methods in the request specs you have to include them with

```
include SessionsHelper
```